# Not able to connect to WiFi after installing ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Windows 10 and after successful installation I am not able to connect to the WiFi network to complete some other activities.

I tried all the solutions suggested like modifying NetworkConfig.conf and restarting the network service but nothing worked for me.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

Following is the result when execute the above command:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the command you shared helped me to understand the actual issue. I fixed it without any workaround with default settings by Ubuntu while installing.

Answer (score 2):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell.conf <<< "blacklist dell_wmi"
```

and reboot.